# Is there an omitted relativizer?

Tags: meaning

> From her [Joad’s mother] position as healer, her hands had grown sure and cool and quiet; from her position as arbiter she had become as remote and faultless in judgment as a goddess. She seemed to know that if she swayed the family shook, and if she ever really deeply wavered or despaired the family would fall, **the family will to function would be gone**.
>   (John Steinbeck, The Grapes of Wrath)

Is there an omitted relativizer (*that* or *which*) after *the family*? Even if there's an omission, do you have any difficulty grasping the meaning at once, without hesitation or second thought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is clear from the fact that it is followed by a marked infinitive (*to function* rather than bare *function*), *will* in this clause is not a verb but a noun:

> **1** [countable, uncountable] the ability to control your thoughts and actions in order to achieve what you want to do; a feeling of strong determination to do something that you want to do
>        [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/will_4)

*The family will to function* is the family's determination to continue living as a family.

If anything is missing here it is a conjunction *and*:

> if she ever really deeply wavered or despaired
>   the family would fall AND
>   the family will to function would be gone.

By omitting the conjunction Steinbeck makes clear that these are not two consequences but one: the second clause stands in apposition to the first as an expansion or explanation of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would insert ("i.e.") as a "relativzer" in the sentence. That is, "if she ever really deeply wavered or despaired the family would fall; **i.e.,** the family will to function would be gone."

(I.e." means *id est* or "that is.") The insertion of it is, of course, mine.